# apply tactic cannot find an instance for a variable

Tags: coq

I have been trying out `apply` tactic in various scenarios and it seems to stuck in the following case when premises are like this:

```
  H1 : a
  H2 : a -> forall e : nat, b -> g e
  ============================
   ...
```

When I try `apply H2 in H1.`, it gives me the error:

```
Error: Unable to find an instance for the variable e.
```

Any way for me to bring `forall e : nat, b -> g e` as part of premises. This is the full working code with the above scenario:

```
Lemma test : forall {a b c : Prop} {g : nat} (f : nat -> Prop),
    a /\ (a -> forall {e : nat}, b -> f e) -> c.
Proof.
  intros a b c f g.
  intros [H1 H2].
  (* apply H2 in H1. *)
Abort.
```

Comment: Like @AntonTrunov said: `specialize (H2 H1).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Coq Reference manual, [§8.2.5](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#sec349):

> The tactic `apply` *term* `in` *ident* tries to match the conclusion of the type of *ident* against a non-dependent premise of the type of *term*, trying them from right to left. If it succeeds, the statement of hypothesis *ident* is replaced by the **conclusion** of the type of *term*.

Now, applying the above description to your case, we get the following, Coq tries to replace `H1 : a` with the conclusion of `H2`, i.e. `g e`. To do that it needs to instantiate the universally quantified variable `e` with some value, which Coq cannot obviously infer -- hence the error message you've seen.

Another way to see that is to try a different variant of `apply ... in ...`:

```
eapply H2 in H1.
```

which will give you two subgoals:

```
  ...
  H2 : a -> forall e : nat, b -> g e
  H1 : g ?e
  ============================
  c
```

and

```
  ...
  H1 : a
  H2 : a -> forall e : nat, b -> g e
  ============================
  b
```

The `H1` hypothesis of the first subgoal shows what Coq was going for with the ordinary `apply in` tactic, but in the `eapply in` case the variable `e` got replaced with an existential variable (`?e`). If you are not familiar with existential variables yet, then they are sort of promise you make to Coq that you'll build terms for them later. You are supposed to build the terms implicitly, via unification.

Anyways, `specialize (H2 H1).` might be what you want to do, or something like this

```
pose proof (H2 H1) as H; clear H1; rename H into H1.
```